# How to pass user_id in ajax route datatable Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I have a datatable in Laravel, here is my code

```
$(function() {
        var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            info: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            responsive: true,       
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('detail.user', 'user_id')}}",
         
            columns: [{
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'title',
                    name: 'title',
                    orderable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'content',
                    name: 'content',
                    orderable: false,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'progress',
                    name: 'progress'
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    name: 'status'
                },
                {
                    data: 'kpi',
                    name: 'kpi'
                },
                {
                    data: 'target_selesai',
                    name: 'target_selesai'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ]
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.detailProduct', function() {
           ...
        });
        $('#saveBtn').click(function(e) {
           ...
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.deleteProduct', function() {
           ...
        });

    });
```

I want to get user_id value from url parameter (ex: http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1000000004 ), I've tried code above, but it will return empty value.
Seems like I write wrong code to get url parameter. Because, If I change the `ajax: "{{ route('detail.user', 'user_id')}}",` into `ajax: "{{ route('detail.user', '1000000004')}}",` the program will works as expected. What sould I do? thanks in advance

Comment: why are you put user id on html root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set variable in PHP code using JavaScript. You should not use PHP code on dynamic JavaScript code. There are 2 alternatives :

1. Use static path instead of Laravel route, just change `ajax: "{{ route('detail.user', 'user_id')}}"` to `ajax: "/detail/"+user_id`
2. Send `user_id` variable using Laravel blade view arg. on your controller define user_id like below:

   ```
   return view('index',
           ['user_id', 1000000004]
       );
   ```

   then call it on the blade as php variable (`$user_id`) example `ajax: "{{ route('detail.user', $user_id)}}"`

Answer (score 0):

1. be sure url in routes/web.php, provide one variable passing, ex /name-routes/{id}
2. and then in your controller function take the data id, function function_name($id){ }
3. and the last be sure format return json with format be like { data : [ name : "value name 1", name : "value_name2" ] }